# Angular2: How to fade out box-msg after a while which is displayed onClick

Tags: javascript, angular, fadeout

Might be a silly question but am new to `angular` and still learning.

Am showing a success message on button click which I need to fade out after few seconds.

```
<div *ngIf="hideSharedLinkCopyMessage" class="alert alert-success box-msg " role="alert">
    <strong>Link Generated!</strong> Your sharable link is copied to clipboard.
</div>
```

Now, am using `alert-success` and `box-msg` classes. I tried to add `fadeOut` class as well but that didn't worked.

`hideSharedLinkCopyMessage` is set to `true` when the button in clicked. Initially it is set to `false` How can I fade this message out after few seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a timeout function after setting `true` `hideSharedLinkCopyMessage`. In the next example the link will fade out after 2 seconds;

```
FadeOutLink() {
    setTimeout( () => {
          this.hideSharedLinkCopyMessage = false;
        }, 2000);
   }
```

An other option and politer is to use Angular Materials and import the [Snackbar](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview) component. Is really easy to use and you can customize it as you want.

Comment: This is exactly what was needed.

Comment: I don't see how you will add fadeout class with this?

Comment: Didn't need to do it here, maybe is easier to do it in css files.

Comment: you define the css in css files. What about adding it to show fadeOut effect. Else how will the fadeout effect start ?

Answer (score 2):

Normal Fade out will not work with *ngif because with `*ngif`, the element is directly removed from the DOM.

You need to use `ngClass` to `add/remove` a class(`fadeout`) which will have the `fade out` effect and then use a timeout to turn your variable `hideSharedLinkCopyMessage` to true and element will be removed from DOM.

**Controller:**

```
<your method to remove alert> () {
    // add class fadeOut here
    setTimeout( () => {
      this.hideSharedLinkCopyMessage = false;
    }, 3000);      
}
```

Comment: what logic you have used to add `fadeOut` class ?

Answer (score 0):

---

Success Message will disappear after 4 sec in angular7

```
  export class UnsubscribeComponent implements OnInit {
  hideSuccessMessage = false;

  FadeOutSuccessMsg() {
    setTimeout( () => {
           this.hideSuccessMessage = true;
        }, 4000);
   }

   component.html -
   ------------------
          <div  *ngIf="!hideSuccessMessage">
            <div class="col-12">
              <p class="alert alert-success">
                  <strong [ngClass] ="FadeOutSuccessMsg()" >You are successfully 
                  unsubscribe from this email service.</strong>                 
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
```