# angular display fading tick box when successfully saved

Tags: angular, fade

In an angular component I need to display a tick box and fade it away when a save is successful.  What is the best way to get his done.  I know I need to use the following css

```
.default {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

What I'm confused about is to when to show this through a `.ts` value and then how do I switch the component to hide.  Essentially how to show it when the save is successful and then achieve the hiding effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use the angular material module to do this:
https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/examples

Comment: I just need to display it next to an input and so far I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50267212/angular2-how-to-fade-out-box-msg-after-a-while-which-is-displayed-onclick, however I am wondering if there is an easier way to get this done rather than using timing functions inside javascript.